# Error has eccurred in Eclipse during importing class

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-juno

I am working on Spring MVC project in Eclipse Juno. I have a few packages with my classes. Once I have used one class in another from different package I have occured this error in pop-up message:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
assertion failed:
```

And there is not nothing more informations. What should I do in Eclipse to prevent such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read about [What is assertion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html).
And looks like assertions are enabled try to run program after disabling it.